# how to remove div from clone(jQuery - remove element's parent row)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have add clone (more than 3) and remove clone button. when i try to clone

```
        <div class="data-add">
        <div class="form-group" id="id1">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Image* : </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
<input id="input-702" name="userfile[]" type="file"class="file-loading">
        </div>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group clearfix" id="id2">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">option* :
                </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    <select name="option[]" autocomplete="off">
        <option>name1</option>
        <option>name2</option>
        <option>name3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <button class="add"  type="button">Add Another </button>


   <button class="remove" id="remove">   remove  </button>  

$(".add").click(function(){
     $("#id1").clone().appendTo(".data-add");
     $("#id2").clone().appendTo(".data-add");
});
```

It clone  particular div happening proper. when i click remove its not working
(not able to remove)

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("#id1").remove();
         $(this).closest("#id2").remove();
});
```

i have tried this also

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("#id1").remove();
         $(this).parents("#id2").remove();
});

$(".remove").click(function(){
   $("#id1").remove();
   $("#id2").remove();
});
```

when i used like this it removing first clone(first id1 and id2). not removing current clone div

Comment: First of all avoid duplicate `id` ....

Comment: Can you add the content of .data-add?

Comment: please post some more html code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ID` first of all, like below.

```
var newId = 10; // Sample ID To Append
var startID = ["id1_", id2_];
$(".add").click(function(){
     var oldId = newId;
     startID[0].replace(oldId, newId);
     startID[1].replace(oldId, newId);
     var newId++;
     $("#id1").clone().attr('id', startID[0]).addClass("clonedDiv").appendTo(".data-add");
     $("#id2").clone().attr('id', startID[1]).addClass("clonedDiv").appendTo(".data-add");
});
```

Then use the new `ID` or the common class `.clonedDiv` to remove them.

Comment: `.attr('id', 'id1_new')` is changing the `id` @roshan

Comment: For me cloning is working proper.only remove part is not woking. i posted  html code also

Comment: Hi i have tried above code also. remove is not woking

Comment: hi i have updated in https://jsfiddle.net/ram77/jw5q1tsj/15/  problem is more than one clone remove is not woking . (it removing all clone )

Comment: Working fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/jw5q1tsj/18/, You didnt include jquery. :)

Comment: hi void, when i click remove, after two clone(third clone), its removing all the div expect first div. i need to remove that div only. when i clone three . i click remove in third. it should remove only third. not second. waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

Elements having `#id1` and `#id2` are being added in the DOM dynamically, so you should use `.on()` function to bind your events e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
   $("#id1").remove();
   $("#id2").remove();
});
```

Comment: when i click remove it removing first div, not removing  current clone div

Comment: My answer was for the removal part only. Using repeated IDs isn't valid. So, for that part you can use code of @void and merge my code for the removal part and use `.clonedDiv` instead of id selectors. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/6mgzy0ra/, it still works, however I would still recommend to use dynamic ids or class.

Comment: hi i have updated in http://jsfiddle.net/ram77/jw5q1tsj/12/  problem is more than one clone  remove is not woking